# change custom tab view

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, page-layout

i have created a custom object which is also displayed in a tab like this:[image]

the object has other columns as well like lookup field to contact object and message text field. how can i display that in the above images as well ? Now it is showing only 1 column but it should show all 3.
I searched in page layout but i was unable to help myself.
we can change the displayed columns from the right gear icon but only for all messages not for recent messages which is shown by default."select fields to display" is disabled in recent messages.

Comment: Click on the top right gear icon and then click on the **select fields to display** and adjust the fields you want to show.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 it was so easy. thanku. how to accept comment as an answer?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 it only works when all messages is selected but by default recent messages is showed and for recent messages "selects field to display" is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default view when you click the Object on the navigation bar is "Recently Viewed" and for the time being you cannot make changes to it. There's an idea to be able to set a default list view for the user. See this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cM0fQAE) for details.

To be able to select the fields that you need to display in the "Recently Viewed" list view, you need to configure it in the search layout. Follow the [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_recent_records_list_lex.htm&type=5) for details on how to choose fields to be shown in the "Recently Viewed" list view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the top right gear icon and then click on the **select fields to display** and adjust the fields you want to show. And make sure you are on the All items list filter. Doesn't work with the recent list filter.